# php form to sort results in xml format from api

Tags: php, xml, forms, api, curl

I have this code which prints certain results pulled from API xml

```
 <?php
  echo "<h1>Approval Stats</h1><br /><br />"; 
      echo "Report for Agent Name: <b>Bhaskar</b><br />"; 

 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://login.leadkitchen.com/affiliates/api/4/reports.asmx/CampaignSummary' );



 $post_array = array(
         'api_key' => 'abc',
         'affiliate_id' => 'abc',
        'start_date' => '10/8/2012',
       'end_date' => '10/11/2012',
       'sub_affiliate' => 'email',
     'start_at_row' => '1',
        'row_limit' => '0',
     'sort_field' => 'offer_name',
     'sort_descending' => 'true'
      );

      //url-ify the data
      foreach($post_array as $key=>$value) 
     { 
          $post_array_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
      }
      $post_array_string = rtrim($post_array_string,'&');
      //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($post_array ));
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_array_string);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
     // print_r($response);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "Process Name: "; echo $xml->campaigns->campaign->vertical_name, PHP_EOL;
    echo "Approvals: "; echo $xml->campaigns->campaign->conversions, PHP_EOL;
    echo "Applied: "; echo $xml->campaigns->campaign->clicks, PHP_EOL;




?>
```

Possible xml response in this link http://z4site.com/social/pay/summary.php

```
<campaigns>
<campaign>

<vertical_name>Free Stuff</vertical_name>

<clicks>6</clicks>
<conversions>1</conversions>

</campaign>
</campaigns>
```

but I need to create a form to actually let the user enter these fields manually before generating the result using ajax.

1. sub_affiliate
2. start_date
3. end_date

from this para

```
 $post_array = array(
     'api_key' => 'abc',
     'affiliate_id' => 'abc',
    'start_date' => '10/8/2012',
   'end_date' => '10/11/2012',
   'sub_affiliate' => 'email',
 'start_at_row' => '1',
    'row_limit' => '0',
 'sort_field' => 'offer_name',
 'sort_descending' => 'true'
  );
```

how do I do that..should I create a HTML file for that? can you suggest me the code please?
thanks

html file http://z4site.com/social/pay/report.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="summary.php">
<input type="text" name="sub_affiliate" />
<input type="text" name="start_date" />
<input type="text" name="end_date" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic HTML+PHP interaction. You can use the following code to check to make sure they have submitted the form with valid inputs so that you don't execute the fetch code on the API until they do so.

`if(!empty($_POST['sub_affiliate'])&&!empty($_POST['start_date'])&&!empty($_POST['end_date'])){//do stuff}`

In your HTML below , you can use a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="sub_affiliate" />
    <input type="text" name="start_date" />
    <input type="text" name="end_date" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: could you elaborate please? I am new to coding. I am getting errors..thanks

Comment: You're going to have to add all the errors you are getting into your question up above. Give me all the code you are using and all errors you are experiencing. Tell me what you are confused about, etc.

Comment: i made a new html page with the above form. and i inserted that php line in the above code.. its giving errors.. where should i insert the codes that you mentioned?

Comment: It says you have a syntax error. Probably a missing { or }. Verify your syntax using a PHP verifier or something.

Comment: This time error not coming, but the result is not displaying :( could you please help me with where to paste the if statement on the php file?

Comment: I think you need to sit down and learn the basics of PHP first. Go do some tutorials and the answer I gave will make perfect sense. :]